# Стилистические ошибки

Tags: стилистика

Это не домашнее задание, это очень небольшой (всего 6 предложений) тренировочный учебный текст из Интернета для проверки орфографической грамотности. Там встречаются такие выражения:

1) а те в свою очередь противопоставляли **истинному пессимизму** новое мировоззрение;

2) поэтому, касаясь различных вопросов, **они** по большинству **из них**  находили компромисс;

3) **Диалог между мировоззрениями** и традиционное воспитание **вместе** не дают гражданам дегенерировать и способствуют прогрессу.

Есть ли здесь стилистические неточности? Почему-то текст вызывает если не "истинный пессимизм", то очень близкий к нему.

Примечание:

А вообще-то "истинный пессимизм", как оказывается, существует, но при этом: "Истинный пессимизм слишком мучителен для того, чтобы с ним мог ужиться человек". [Л. И. Шестов. Шекспир и его критик Брандес (1898)]

Comment: Могу предложить заменить "они по большинству из них находили" на "они, как правило, находили", но не могу утверждать, что предложенный вариант никуда не годится...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вижу ни стилистических ошибок, ни неточностей. Для понимания нужен весь текст, вырванные из контекста фразы всегда кажутся странными. В этом тексте всё понятно:

*Привилегированная интеллигенция вступила в диалог с претендентами на должность президента. Кандидатов на высокий пост обвиняли в мошенничестве, а те в свою очередь противопоставляли **истинному пессимизму** новое мировоззрение. Интеллигенция старалась склонить претендентов к ностальгическим чувствам, но их с презрением окрестили дилетантами и некомпетентными специалистами. Надо иметь в виду, что **спорящие** были ровесниками и их поколение воспитывалось под влиянием одной идеологии. Поэтому, касаясь различных **вопросов**, **они** по большинству **из них** все равно находили компромисс.  Диалог  между  мировоззрениями  и традиционное воспитание вместе не дают гражданам дегенерировать и способствуют прогрессу.*

1. "Истинный пессимизм"- это, скорее всего,  философское понятие "**гносеологический пессимизм"** – античные софисты, киники, неоплатоники, Д. Юм, И. Кант утверждали, что вопрос об истинности знания не может быть решён окончательно. А если познание реальности и возможно, то только на уровне нашего чувственного опыта.Скептики  выражают сомнение в возможности достоверного знания, т. к. его исходный пункт – наши субъективные и ненадёжные чувственные восприятия.
2. "поэтому, касаясь различных вопросов, они по большинству из них находили компромисс"

**Они**-спорящие, **из них** - из вопросов.

3. Диалог между мировоззрениями и традиционное воспитание вместе не дают гражданам дегенерировать и способствуют прогрессу.

А где здесь неточность? Как говорится, в споре рождается истина. Всё верно. В чём вопрос?

"Диалог мировоззрений" - нормальный философский термин, как и "диалог культур".

Comment: *"Диалог мировоззрений" - нормальный философский термин...* Ну вот, но "между-то" лишнее, нет? И "вместе" мне тоже не нравится. По-моему, и без него понятно.

Comment: И то и другое корректно. Диалог кого и диалог между кем и кем. "И между ними произошёл следующий диалог..."; "Их диалог касался ..."

Comment: Я не знаю, откуда текст, о чём он. Может быть, речь об идеалистической философии, материалистической и традиционном воспитании - они вместе дают результат, совместный, а не каждый в отдельности. Ну вот как в советской семье коммунистическое воспитание и религия бабушки + строгость родителей.

Comment: Или оптимисты, пессимисты и традиционное воспитание.

Comment: *И то и другое корректно. Диалог кого и диалог между кем и кем.* Возможно, Вы и правы, но, что касается этого словосочетания, Гугл выдаёт на порядки больше примеров без "между" (если закавычивать) — 8 520 против 102.

Comment: Ну, в любом случае, не ошибка, придираететесь, батенька.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,  значит, здесь всё нормально, не стоит огорчаться. Меня удивила фраза "они по большинству из них" (при первом прочтении думала, что  это одни и те же "они"), да еще показалось странным наречие "вместе" в заключительном выводе, очень оптимистическом.

Comment: Мне эта фраза тоже не понравилась. Её можно улучшить перестановкой слов (... по большинству из них они...) - чтобы "них" не цеплялось за "они", а то и заменить "из них" на "таковых" (по аналогии с "он сказал такому-то, чтобы _тот_...").

Comment: _Диалог кого и диалог между кем и кем._ Это можно относить к людям. Проблема в том, что здесь выходит "диалог между чем и чем" - это _пересказ_ распространённой _метафоры_ "диалог мировоззрений" (ср. революция роз -> революция, совершённая розами).

Comment: *Проблема в том, что здесь выходит "диалог между чем и чем".* Вот-вот, и я о том же подумал вчера, только не написал.

Comment: Диалог между чем и чем тоже возможен - это метонимия, как "спорили две школы" - мы ж понимаем, что не здания(или взгляды), а люди спорят. Спор между западниками и славянофилами=спор между западничеством и славянофильством. Я нашла, откуда это - с  VI Российского философского конгресса в Нижнем Новгороде , там академики выступали, на ошибки их наверняка специалисты проверили.